# Multivariate t-distribution

Tags: r

Given the degrees of freedom, location, and shape matrix of a (central) multivariate t-distibution, how would one use R to calculate joint probabilities?

The 'mvtnorm' package does not allow for a location vector to be inputed.

Comment: Isn't non-zero location handled by non-centrality parameter vector $\delta$ in pmvt https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/mvtnorm.pdf ?  I guess it gets a bit complicated. @ whuber , at first thought I figured this question would be off-topic, however, given the complexity, subtlety, and role of the non-centrality parameter vector, I believe keeping it open might be appropriate.

Comment: @JLO simply shift it? If you want a cdf at $a$ for a central t with location $\mu$ that's the same as finding it for $a-\mu$ and setting the location parameter to $0$.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. @Glen_b Shifting worked. Also, just for reference, setting the vector of non-centrality parameters, delta, equal to the location vector and setting the 'type' argument equal to "shifted" obtains the required joint probabilities.

Comment: Interesting; I wasn't aware it had a "shifted" argument: it's not really a noncentrality parameter then, but that misnomer is beside the point. Looks like @MarkL.Stone was right so I deleted my comment relating to it.

Comment: @Glen_b The description of the 'delta' argument is "the vector of noncentrality parameters of length n, for type = "shifted" delta specifies the mode." If you do not set type =  "shifted" it should work as a noncentrality parameter.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I understood this from your earlier comment; my issue was just about the reference to a location-shift as a t-noncentrality parameter.